# F# Type Providers inconsitent behaviour

Tags: f#, type-providers, f#-interactive, f#-data

I want to create a sequence of 'candles' ( a simple structure) for performing testing on financial data. I have downloaded some financial data from a broker and they are in a csv format.

I have the following code, using type providers:

```
type DukasCandles = CsvProvider<"C:\Users\**\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\FI\FI\Data\schema.csv" > 

let row2Candle (myTicker: string )  (mySide: Side)  (aRow:DukasCandles.Row)  : Candle = 
    {Open = aRow.Open ; 
     Close = aRow.Close;  
     Low = aRow.Low
     High = aRow.High
     StartTime  = aRow.LocalTime    
     Volume = aRow.Volume  
     Ticker = myTicker
     Side = mySide } 

let  sortedCandles aTicker aParsedFile  = 
    aParsedFile 
    |> Seq.map   ( row2Candle aTicker Side.Bid  ) 
    |> Seq.sortBy ( fun candle -> candle.StartTime)  

let fileContent = inputFile |> DukasCandles.Load 
let rows = fileContent.Rows
let dataContent = rows|> (sortedCandles "EUR_USD")
```

It is just a toy example to test my understanding of type providers. I have it in a FSX script after the necessary boilerplate for declaring the file name and open the necessary modules.

Now the question: if I highlight this as it is and try to execute in F# interactive, then type

```
dataContent;;
```

I get the following message

```
val it : seq<Candle> =


 Error: Couldn't parse row 1057 according to schema: Expecting DateTime in LocalTime, got 13.01.2016 00:00:00.000
```

The odd thing is the following:
suppose I type the following code in F# interactive:

```
fileContent;;
```

get the answer and then refer to it through the 'it' keyword, as in:

```
it.Rows |> sortedCandles "EUR_USD";;
```

Then the code is executed with no problems.

Why do we have such an inconsistent behaviour? Any idea?
Any help highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: F# interactive might be using a different culture

Comment: Also the first excecution is in F# interactive. The first one sends all the code to F# interactive, whereas the second one relies on it instead of the variable fileContent. Hope this clarifies. Thanks

Comment: Anyone? Any idea?